# Select html input element in ant-select

Tags: html, testing, css-selectors, automated-tests, testcafe

I want to input some text into an Ant Select field within a modal in test cafe.

This is the HTML I'm working with:[image: htmlForProject]  I open two modals in the test, so the one I'm interested in is the second one.  Currently, I've tried the following to identify it but each time I run the test in test cafe I'm told `The element that matches the specified selector is not visible.` on the line `.typeText(LayerNameInputForDeletion, layerName, { replace: true })`:

```
/*
goal: open layer adding modal, close it by 
hitting OK, thus accepting the current settings.
Then open layer deleting modal and remove the new layer
 */
test('Can open and accept default layer adding pop up', async t => {

    let layerName = "MyGreatLayer";

    ...

    //open second modal
    await t
        .click('#LayerDeletingPopUpButtonID');

    //select layer delete OK button
    const LayerDeletingModalOKButton = Selector('div.ant-modal').nth(1)
        .find('div.ant-modal-footer')
        .find('button.ant-btn-primary');

    //XXX this selector fails to find the element
    //select the input field from ant Select to enter layer name
    const LayerNameInputForDeletion = Selector('div.ant-modal').nth(1)
        .find('div.ant-modal-body')
        .find('input.ant-select-search__field');

    //click the OK button from the second modal after typing in the layer name
    await t
        .expect(LayerDeletingModalOKButton.with({visibilityCheck: true}).exists)
        .ok({timeout: 30000})
        .hover(LayerDeletingModalOKButton)
        //this typing step fails to find the element
        .typeText(LayerNameInputForDeletion, layerName, { replace: true })
        .click(LayerDeletingModalOKButton);
});
```

This selector fails to find the input field in the ant-Select field:

```
const LayerNameInputForDeletion = Selector('div.ant-modal').nth(1)
    .find('div.ant-modal-body')
    .find('input.ant-select-search__field');
```

I've tried a few different selectors to no avail:

Something more specific:

```
const LayerNameInputForDeletion = Selector('div.ant-modal').nth(1)
    .find('div.ant-modal-body')
    .find('div.ant-select-selection__rendered')
    .find('div.ant-select-search')
    .find('input.ant-select-search__field');
```

The exact path given when I select "copy selector" from the "inspect" page in Chrome:

```
const LayerNameInputForDeletion = Selector('body > div:nth-child(9) > div > 
    div.ant-modal-wrap > div > div.ant-modal-content > 
    div.ant-modal-body > div > div > div > 
    div.ant-select-search.ant-select-search--inline > div > input');
```

A combination of above approaches:

```
const LayerNameInputForDeletion = Selector('div.ant-modal').nth(1)
        .find("div.ant-modal-content > 
               div.ant-modal-body > div > div > div > 
               div.ant-select-search.ant-select-search--inline > 
               div > input");
```

What am I missing here? How can I select that element to type into?

Comment: Your `LayerNameInputForDeletion` selector looks valid. For further research you need to update your question with a sample project (or public URL) to reproduce this issue. Note: you can use TestCafe Studio to [record your test](https://docs.devexpress.com/TestCafeStudio/400165/guides/record-tests), then you can see all needed selectors in the [converted test code](https://docs.devexpress.com/TestCafeStudio/400182/user-interface/explorer-panel#convert-recorded-tests-to-javascript).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parent div has `style="display: none;"`.

So you cannot type a text into an invisible input field.